# Alfresco configure categories root in replication job

Tags: replication, categories, alfresco, alfresco-share

I've configured categories in one of my Alfresco servers. I've configured replication job for few folders as well to replicate content from one server to another server.

I want to configure categories root to replicate from one server to another. What should I select as source payload for this kind of replication job?

Answer (score 0):

Below link can guide you setting up replication job.

http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/tasks/adminconsole-replication-create.html

Comment: I am aware about how to configure replication jobs for spaces and selection. The question is how to set categories root for that?